# Application crashes after I closed the socket waiting for reading in a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, socketexception

I have a service running in background which contains several threads reading and writing over TCP sockets. My application crashes after I close the sockets and stop the service. There is a SocketException thrown and catched by my code before the crash happens. I have no idea why the SocketExeption causes my application crashing when its been catched already. But this issue only occurs in one of my phones running on android 4.2. No crash happens on android 5 or andoird 6 so far.

Below is part of the code:

```
public void logout() throws IOException {
this.userName = "";
listenerService.p_status=false;
listenerService.p_Thread.interrupt();
listenerService.c_status=false;
listenerService.c_Thread.interrupt();
listenerService.closeSocket();
unbindService(mConnection);
listenerService.stopService();
```

}

Here is the debug information:

```
04-05 17:36:49.635 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt I/System.out: SOCKET CLOSED!
04-05 17:36:49.635 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
04-05 17:36:49.635 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
04-05 17:36:49.635 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:142)
04-05 17:36:49.640 28101-28699/com.androidapp.ptt I/System.out: 404:kukukukukukuku
04-05 17:36:49.640 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
04-05 17:36:49.640 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:499)
04-05 17:36:49.640 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
04-05 17:36:49.640 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
04-05 17:36:49.645 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
04-05 17:36:49.645 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
04-05 17:36:49.645 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt W/System.err:     at com.androidapp.ptt.ListenerService$2.run(ListenerService.java:439)
04-05 17:36:49.645 28101-28691/com.androidapp.ptt W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-05 17:36:49.685 28101-28101/com.androidapp.ptt I/System.out: Service done!
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Show stacktrace (there are multiple options for getting SocketException) and show more code. Probably you didnt close input/output stream or something

Comment: Now I added the debug info to the question. I just closed the socket, not explicitly shutdown the inputstream and outputstream. But I think the input and output stream should be closed automatically after the socket closed.The crash only happens in android 4.2, no problem with android 5.0 or 6.0.

Comment: try to check if socket closed already or not before close() it.

Comment: I am sure the socket is open before the close(). I could send and receive messages over the socket until I call logout() method. I guess may be I should keep the socket open and send a message over the socket to tell the server the client has quit. Then I could reuse this socket later when I need.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My code about socket is too messy to post. But You are right, it is not correctly written. I did not successfully stop the loop in the thread after I close the socket. And I had an issue related to multiple thread. Because of the multiple threads' unexpected execute order, one of my caught Excetpion.printStackTrace() could be called after the service containing these threads has been terminated by another thread, then lead the application crashing.

Answer (score 1):

The *thread* that was blocked in `read()` threw an `IOException`. This is exactly the behaviour that should be expected. You closed the socket: it's closed. You can't continue reading.

If you want a nice way to terminate that thread, call `shutdownInput()` on the socket instead of closing it. That will cause the reading thread to unblock, perceive end of stream, and, if correctty written, stop reading and close the socket.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation helps a lot. Its better to unblock the read() by shutdownInput() than throwing an exception. And my code did not correctly stop the thread and close the socket. Also I found an interesting thing: Calling Exception.printStackTrace() could cause a uncaught exceptions maybe because of the multiple threads' unexpected execute order. Excetpion.printStackTrace() could be called after the service containing these threads has been terminated by another thread, then lead the application crashing.